# Использование одного Provisioning Profile на разных компьютерах

Tags: xcode, mobile-development

Есть необходимость тестировать проект из `Xcode` с разных компьютеров на разных `iOS`-устройствах. Товарищ, который является владельцем профайла скинул его мне, я установил его в `Organizer`, но он не появился в `Xcode` и не установился в `iPhone` при синхронизации его через `iTunes` (`UDID` устройства добавлен в профайл). В результате не имею возможности выбрать данный профайл в `Xcode->Build Settings->Code Signing`. При компиляции с таргетом на устройстве получаю "`No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates`". Пробовали экспортировать сертификат из `Keychain`, но это не помогло. Пробовал очищать лист и добавлять профайл заново, тоже безуспешно. Как поступить, чтобы решить ситуацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может кому-то будет полезно - решение оказалось весьма тривиальным: перед тем как установить в Xcode новую версию профайла может понадобится удаление старых сертификатов и экспорт сертификата с нового профайла. Раньше этого делать не нужно было, но вероятно что-то изменилось в процессе подписывания, точную зависимость найти пока не удалось.

Answer (score 2):

Так не получится. У вас проблема в том, что у вас нету сертификата, для которого выдан профайл.

`Provisioning profile` - это комбинация сертификата (`development` в данном случае), `appid` (идентификатор приложения) и списка девайсов (до 100 штук разных, на которых можно тестить приложение).

Смотрите последовательность действий: [Публикуем приложение в AppStore](http://heximal.ru/blog/apple/publikuem-prilozhenie-v-appstore/), плюс в `Provisioning Portal'е` есть видеоролики по этой процедуре.

Кстати чтоб тестировать приложение на разных девайсах нет необходимости собирать приложение на разных компьютерах. Достаточно рассылать тестерам `ipa` файл. `Build and archive`, в `Organizer'е` этот `ipa` можно сохранить, разослать мылом или подписать для публикации.

Comment: Дело в том что сертификат экспортировали на из кейчейна товарища в мой, но по прежнему без результата. И мы пишем и тестим код а не уже готовый .ipa, поэтому такой вариант нам не подходит. То есть хотим работать на двух машинах с одним профайлом. Раньше мы уже так делали - он просто пересылал мне свой профайл, я добавлял его в Xcode, но с некоторых пор судя по всему что-то изменилось, так как теперь уже так не получается.

Comment: А в keychan'е у вас нормально проимпортировался сертификат? с личным и открытым ключом? Короче вам видимо надо разобраться с сертификатом. Профайл - следующий этап.
Должен быть:

- открытый ключ
- личный ключ
     - сертификат к этому личному ключу.

Я бы делал так. Импортировал открытый и личный ключи (взятые с другой машины), взял бы .cer файл со страницы  provisioning protal'а, попытался бы его установить. Если все встало нормально, то дальше  provisioning profile  устанаваливал.

Comment: ЗЫ У нас такой проблемы нету, на юр.лицо подписка оформлена, там каждый член команды (apple id) имеет свой сертификат, и подписывает приложения своим provisioning profile'ом.